# Responsive side scrolling blog page issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a blog post page for a client and have used a table with the help of Jquery to make it infinitely side scrolling.  The issue is that I want it to NOT side scroll when smaller than 740px.  The table seems to get glitchy when I mess with the jquery and resize commands.  I tried unwrapping the td and it got very glitchy.

```
<script>
      $(function(){
       $("#page-wrap").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='10px'><tr>");
        $(".post").wrap("<td>");
     });

    </script>
```

And here is the body of what's being effected.

```
<div id="page-wrap">
      <article class="post">
        <img src="assets/images/tumblr_nqvdnry3Du1ttpk3mo1_1280.jpg"><p>This is a caption!</p>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
      <img src="assets/images/tumblr_nqvdktfpUS1ttpk3mo3_1280.jpg"><p>This is a caption!</p>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
      <img src="assets/images/tumblr_nqvdktfpUS1ttpk3mo2_1280.jpg"><p>This is a caption!</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Here is the css attached to it

```
td {
        img {
            max-height: 74vh;
            max-width: 1280px;
    }
    p {
        font-size:14px;
        font-family: Gill Sans;
        margin-bottom:0;
        line-height: 1.04;
    }
}
```

I have used vh to make the images responsive and be the height of the window.  When I get to 740px I want it to switch to scrolling down.  Someone suggested using jquery to dynamically get the size of all the image widths on the page but I can't make it not wrap.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out but now have another issue.  Here is the solution first.  Ditched the table and wrote script to fix it for me.

```
(function($){
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  var windowW = $(window).width();

   $(window).on('load', function(){

      if(windowW >= windowH) {//this is horizontal
        var allImgWidth = 0;
         $('article img').each(function(){
            allImgWidth += $(this).width() + 10 ;//10 is padding
        });
        $('html, body').width(allImgWidth);   //makes page width of all images and padding that I have set elsewhere
        $('article img').height(windowH - 150);//this accounts for header height and margin height from top

        $('article img').css('margin-left', '10px');
        } else {
           $('article img').width(windowW);//if window width is not greater than window height, the images are the width of the original window


      };
      if(windowW >= windowH) {
        (function() {
        function scrollHorizontally(e) {
            e = window.event || e;
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*80); // Multiplied by 80 (increases speed of scroll)
            document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*80); // Multiplied by 80
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
            // Firefox
            window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
        } else {
            // IE 6/7/8
            window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
        }
        })();//function scrollHorizontally ends
        } else {
      };//else ends
  });//onload ends 

})(jQuery);//fucntion ends


(function($){
   $(window).resize(function(){
      var windowH = $(window).height();
      var windowW = $(window).width();
      if(windowW >= windowH) { //horizontal
        var allImgWidth = 0;
         $('article img').each(function(){
            allImgWidth += $(this).width() + 10 ;
        });
        $('html, body').width(allImgWidth);   
        $('article img').height(windowH - 150);
        $('article img').css('width','auto');//dynamically resizes pics
        $('article img').css('margin-left', '10px');
      } else { //vertical
        $('html, body').scrollLeft=0;
        $('html, body').width(windowW);  
        $('article img').width(windowW);
        $('article img').css('height','auto');
        $('article img').css('margin-top', '10px');

      };
      if(windowH >= windowW) {
        $(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
           if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
                    // scroll up
                }
                else {
                    // scroll down
                }
});
        } else {
           $(window).off('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
           (function() {
        function scrollHorizontally(e) {
            e = window.event || e;
            var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*80); // Multiplied by 80 (increases speed of scroll)
            document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*80); // Multiplied by 80
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
            window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
            // Firefox
            window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
        } else {
            // IE 6/7/8
            window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
        }
        })();//function scrollHorizontally ends

      };
  });//window resize ends


})(jQuery);//function ends
```

Now though, on initial page load the site is 40,000px wide.  On resizing from vertical to horizontal, it's fine and fits.  Not sure what is causing this.